# Vector tiles to MBTiles

Tags: raster, mapbox, tilemill, mbtiles, vector-tiles

I need some clarification regarding MBTiles.

I am generating MBTiles in 2 different ways:

1. Using TileMill
2. Using Mapbox tm2 to MBTile using TileCloud

In TileMill, does the exported MBTile contain vector data or just raster images?

In TileCloud, I am generating MBTiles from a tm2 so I am assuming that the exported MBTiles from this process are vectors?

So I read somewhere that MBTiles can contain raster OR vectors.
Are vector MBTiles smaller in size and better than rastered ones?

Answer (score 4):

MBTiles is a fairly generic tile-based packaging format which is agnostic about containing either vector data or raster data.

> In TileMill, does the exported MBTile contain vector data or just raster images?

Raster. Tilemill is strictly a raster tile generator.

> In TileCloud, I am generating MBTiles from a tm2 so I am assuming that the exported MBTiles from this process are vectors?

I don't know TileCloud, but I assume so.

> So I read somewhere that MBTiles can contain raster OR vectors. Are vector MBTiles smaller in size and better than rastered ones?

They're two very different things. They are usually smaller. Whether they're "better" depends entirely on what you're going to do with them. Raster tiles are obviously better for simply displaying in a wide range of browsers, applications etc. Vector tiles have advantages in dynamically styling, efficient data transfer, and delegating rendering to the client.